# Chapéus Secretos no Winter Bash 2014

Tags: debate, winterbash-2014

Muito provavelmente os mais desocupados de nós já se engajaram no espírito de fim de ano da Stack Exchange com os chapéus do [Winter Bash 2014](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/12/winter-bash-2014/?cb=1).

Se você participa, muito provavelmente percebeu que não existem apenas os 30 chapéus visíveis. Algumas ações em particular recompensam outros chapéus classificados como "secretos".

E talvez já tenha até procurado a respeito e encontrado posts no METÃO como [esse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245170/winter-bash-2014-secret-hats) e [esse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245170/winter-bash-2014-secret-hats/245200).

Vamos simplificar as coisas pros brazucas e listar os 8 Chapéus Secretos:

- **Fascinating**:

[image: Fascinating]

Esse chapéus é recebido após votar positivamente em alguma coisa da qual você gostou.

- **Chameleon**

[image: Chameleon]

Esse chapéu é recebido quando se edita algo no seu Perfil. Porém, dependendo do quão preenchido seu Perfil já esteja, você pode não receber esse chapéu por simplesmente editar algo.

Comigo foi assim e como alternativa basta se inscrever em outro site da Stack Exchange. Eu me inscrevi no AskUbuntu com a mesma conta do GMail que uso aqui.

- **Warm Welcome**

[image: Warm Welcome]

Esse chapéu é recebido por votar positivamente para uma pergunta de um recém-chegado.

- **Time Lord**

[image: Time Lord]

Esse foi bem difícil pois requer que 5 publicações antigas sejam editadas.

A dificuldade foi em encontrar algo que justificasse a edição pois esse chapéu está relacionado com as Medalhas [Escavador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/75/excavator) e [Arqueólogo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/74/archaeologist), o que aumenta a "competitividade".

- **Hairboat**

[image: Hairboat]

Esse provavelmente deve ter sido uma homenagem à um dos funcionários da Stack Exchange pois ele é dado àqueles que respondem ou comentam algo postado por [Abby Hairboat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/165581/abby-hairboat)

*Mas e qual o propósito desse tópico?*

Bom... Eu sou maníaco por *gamification* e eu não satisfaria essa neura se eu não pelo menos tentasse obter o:

- **Eureka**

[image: Eureka]

Dado àqueles que descobrem alguma coisa sobre os Chapéus Secretos.

A descrição não é lá grande coisa então, certeza, certeza de que é assim que se ganha, isto é, com *spoilers* no META de cada comunidade, eu não tenho, mas quem não arrisca, não petisca. :D

Existem ainda mais dois, os quais eu ainda<sup>1</sup> não consegui:

- **Waffles**

[image: Waffles]

Recebido ao se mudar de opinião sobre alguma decisão tomada, como votar para reabrir algo editado que você tenha votado pra fechar.

> Aparentemente reverter um voto dado numa pergunta/resposta não conta.

O @bigown e o @Math já conseguiram, mas eu ainda estou sem meu café da manhã. :p

E por último uma variação do **Fascinating**:

- **Fascinating, Ma'am**

[image: Fascinating Ma'am]

Esse aparentemente é dado ao se votar numa pergunta/resposta já bem votada. Não sei o porquê de eu ainda não ter recebido, já que eu dei um *upvote* tanto em perguntas com mais de 50 votos tanto aqui no SOPT quanto no SOEn e nada ainda.

<sup>1 Até o momento dessa edição</sup>

Comment: *Eureka!* Aparentemente deu certo :D

Comment: You f*cking kidding me! hahaha.. Não dava nada por esse post :P Meus parabéns.

Comment: Pior é que nem eu botei muita fé de que daria certo. Quem sabe não jogo na mega, vai que rola... :D

Comment: @BrunoAugusto dá para separar o conteúdo de cada chapéu com -----? Para ficar mais claro.

Comment: Eu já deveria ter melhorado isso... Vamos ver como fica.

Comment: Esse é o post mais _gamer_ do SOpt. kkkk

Comment: Pensei que fosse pra ser secreto, aí acaba a graça da "exclusividade"

Comment: @BrunoAugusto para ganhar o waffle você tem que votar negativo em uma publicação, esperar seu voto ficar bloqueado (algo em torno de 4 ou 5 minutos), editar essa publicação, e então votar a favor dela. PS: Vou exigir meu Eureka por te ajudar! :P

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Eureka!! Eureka!! Eureka!!

Comment: Yeah! Parabéns! :D

Comment: Experimente votar numa *resposta* bem votada, acho que foi assim que ganhei o *Fascinating, Ma'am*.

Answer (score 5):

Gostaria de esclarecer como conseguir um **Waffles hat** já que a descrição na pergunta está equivocada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este chapéu pode ser conquistado por um usuário quando ele vota negativamente em uma pergunta e depois a edita para melhorar sua qualidade, e logo em seguida inverte seu voto para ser positivo.

Comment: Aguardando meu **Eureka hat** ansiosamente.

Comment: O Eureka pelo Waffle [já é meu](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2331/chap%C3%A9us-secretos-no-winter-bash-2014#comment7827_2331) :P

Comment: Mesmo tendo instruções erradas de como conseguir o chapéu? Não faz muito sentido, mas tudo bem.

Comment: Bom, eu não sou o juiz e tb não sei o que está de errado, só sei que ganhei. E não pode ter sido por outra coisa pois não me arrisquei em "resolver" nenhum outro segredo.

Comment: Eu fiz isso, mais de uma vez, e estou com fome até agora.

Comment: Yeaaaaaaaah! Finalmente!

Comment: De nada, @BrunoAugusto. Up vote a minha resposta a hora que quiser :)

Comment: Já votei, apesar de votos aqui no META não serem lá tão importantes.