# A verdade sobre o Waffle Hat

Tags: debate, winterbash-2014

Como foi o único que não foi explicado no post [Chapéus Secretos no Winter Bash 2014](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2331/chap%C3%A9us-secretos-no-winter-bash-2014), o wafle hat para ser conseguido deve:

### Waffles

[image: Wafle]

É obtido votando em uma pergunta, editando-a (mesmo que seja tendo sua edição aprovada) e daí mudar o seu voto.

Aparentemente **respostas não são válidas**, e a edição **deve ser construtiva**.

É desconhecido ainda o critério. Se deve ser mudando em ambas as direções ou somente de DownVote para UpVote.

**Fonte:** Este post do meta [Winter Bash 2014 Secret Hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245170/winter-bash-2014-secret-hats)

---

### Edição

O comentário do @Math explicou primeiro o/ e eu nem tinha visto ;)

Comment: Mas mudar o voto não é possível. Após o voto só se pode remover sem votar novamente - já até abri um meta sobre isso. É isso realmente?

Comment: Pelo menos é o que consta no post do metão. E aparentemente o camarada ganhou o Eureka!

Comment: Opa, eu já expliquei isso aqui no meta, comentário não vale? rs.. [LINK](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2331/chap%C3%A9us-secretos-no-winter-bash-2014#comment7796_2331)

Comment: Erro meu, confundi o 'voto' :)

Comment: @Math Descuido meu! Não tinha visto teu comentario!

Comment: hahaha, de boa! Você oficializou numa resposta e deixou bem mais visível

Comment: @Math mas eu vi que o número de "Eurekas" era limitado a 8 e no primeiro dia todos foram entregues. :( Fica para 2015

Comment: Na vdd acho q ele é limitado pois é um para cada usuário que descobriu o segredo. Acho que o Bruno Augusto ganhou um por compaixão da SE, ou algo assim, rsrs.. pq afinal de contas ele apenas trouxe para cá o post do Metão. Como somos um caso especial de um site em outra lingua acho que resolveram dar um desconto e premiaram ele.