# Chapéus, sapatos, roupas usadas quem tem 2016

Tags: debate, winterbash-2016

## Winter Bash 2016

Mais um fim de ano se aproximando trazendo com ele o tradicional evento Winter Bash!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

PS: Infelizmente são só chapéus. Sapatos e roupas usadas foi por conta do seu madruga.

### Uma pequena introdução

<sup>(retirada do [post do ano passado](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4633/3117) porque <s>eu tava com preguiça de escrever uma nova</s> a explicação ficou tão boa que não precisava de outra)</sup>

Winter Bash é um evento que premia os usuários com chapéus virtuais ao se realizar determinadas tarefas ou atingir conquistas no site, similar as medalhas. Esse chapéus podem ser vestidos nos avatares dos usuários que os conquistarem deixando o avatar engraçado (pelo menos essa é a intenção).

Os chapéus não são vistos por quem não é membro da comunidade, e aqueles que odeiam chapéus podem desativar para não ter que ver os outros se divertindo com chapéus bobos por aí :)

Depois do fim do evento, todos os chapéus desaparecem e não se pode mais usá-los. Os chapéus ganhos em uma determinada edição do evento não podem ser usados em edições subsequentes.

Para quem não conhece e quer ter uma noção do que são os chapéus pode-se ver alguns deles [nesse post](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2331/3117), por exemplo. Boa sorte para entenderem como eles serão usados na cabeça.

### Queremos Winter bash?

Apesar de normalmente considerado divertido a comunidade pode se posicionar contra ou a favor do evento. Para isso podem usar os campos de comentários e respostas, e votando neles também.

Se aprovado ele começa no dia 19 de dezembro desse ano e vai até o dia 8 de janeiro do ano que vem. Se não aprovado não começa. A escolha deve ser tomada até o dia 13 de dezembro.

O ranking e os chapéus conquistados pelos usuários poderão ser acompanhados através da [página do Winter Bash 2016](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: http://g1.globo.com/mundo/noticia/2015/07/australiano-cria-chapeus-para-fazer-amigos.html

Comment: Que venham os chapéus!!

Comment: Winter bash da vida real! Hahaha

Comment: Tem um usuário que chama "MeuChapeu". Já deve estar no clima :p

Comment: @WallaceMaxters [Fui mais rápido](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2288/) :)

Comment: Lembrei de outro entusiasta, o [MagicHat](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/45437/magichat)

Comment: Vamos lá meter um redhat :D

Comment: Vim só pra dar upvote na pergunta por causa do título.

Comment: Qual a necessidade dos downvotes nas postagens? Votem somente up para mostrar o que lhes interessa mais, é sim ou não.

Answer (score 39):

### Eu quero chapéus!

[image]

Comment: Estragou o par de respostas S/N que ficou muito legal, mas realmente você é bem fotogênico :)

Comment: Poisé, eu demorei para tirar a selfie daí na hora que tava postando a outra apareceu, mas achei que poderia compartilhar minha beleza com todos mesmo assim.

Comment: Esse chapéu você ganhou do seu primo o Asa branca? hehe :D

Comment: @rray isso msm, hehehe

Comment: Esse papagaio tem camisa, agora vai ter chapéu...

Comment: Qual a necessidade dos downvotes nas postagens? Votem somente up para mostrar o que lhes interessa mais, é sim ou não.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento concordo, até mesmo por que serão desconsiderados para concluir qual foi a decisão da comunidade

Answer (score 20):

Maneiras educadas de dizer que **eu não quero**:

[image: que tal não]

Um bom motivo para não usarmos chapéus são os ações gratuitas no site sem mérito para conseguir eles, como vários upvotes ou downvotes aleatórios para liberar chapéus (isso é apenas um exemplo), como dito aqui https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2327/3635

Então não use chapéu quando estiver em casa:

[image: não use chapéus dentro de casa]

Comment: Ah cara que droga... o urso me faz querer votar a favor mas eu quero chapéus, e agora??

Comment: Só botar um chapéu de urso

Comment: @Math Vota a favor do urso, ele é seu amigo e provavelmente sabe o que é melhor pra ti :)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters maltrato aos animais?

Comment: Viu só? O urso tá atraindo votos a favor. Essa resposta tem 2 votos enquanto [a do bigown](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5498/3117) que inclusive é mais antiga só tem 1.

Comment: É preciso ser urso! :)

Comment: Qual a necessidade dos downvotes nas postagens? Votem somente up para mostrar o que lhes interessa mais, é sim ou não.

Comment: Qual a necessidade de haver tantas postagens, já que haviam duas que expressavam o sim e o não?

Comment: @ramaral sim estamos discutindo isso no chat

Comment: @ramaral acredito que o erro foi meu tanto na hora de escrever a pergunta que meio que incentivava isso como na hora de postar a resposta do "sim" que fiquei atrasado por alguns segundos e acabei postando mesmo assim. Nos próximos tópicos do meta similares tomarei cuidado para não criar tamanha bagunça.

Answer (score 19):

Quem quer, levante o polegar.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sub><sub>[Fonte da imagem](https://mommywurk.files.wordpress.com/2015/07/thumbs-up.jpg?w=820&h=312&crop=1)</sub></sub>

Comment: Qual a necessidade dos downvotes nas postagens? Votem somente up para mostrar o que lhes interessa mais, é sim ou não.

Answer (score 17):

Demorou, que venham os chapéus:

[image: Imagem meramente ilustrativa]

<sub>Imagem meramente ilustrativa</sub>

Comment: Essa imagem vai fazer o pessoal achar que os chapéus são de verdade, hehehe

Comment: @Math "obsoleto" :p

Comment: "nem tanto" :p.

Comment: @Math Esses poderes de moderador, hein...

Comment: Qual a necessidade dos downvotes nas postagens? Votem somente up para mostrar o que lhes interessa mais, é sim ou não.

Comment: Ah, deixa, downvote no meta pra mim é nada...

Comment: @WallaceMaxters o problema é o que "entoa", nem todos tem privilégio de ver os down e desconsiderar :/

Answer (score 15):

### **SIM.**

Vários. **Ao mesmo tempo!**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual a necessidade dos downvotes nas postagens? Votem somente up para mostrar o que lhes interessa mais, é sim ou não.

Answer (score 14):

Dê chapéus para o gato!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ano passado o tema era "gatos": http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4633/3117

Answer (score 11):

Sim, que venham os chapéus.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acho que estamos discutindo chapéus e não sobre essas maravilhosas distros :)

Comment: Apenas curti a ideia e postei como um belo trocadilho ^^ haha

Answer (score 10):

### O chapéu mais lindo de todos

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

**Não**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A expressao *hat's off* quer dizer demonstrar respeito, mas aqui quero mesmo a tradução literal, tirar o chapéu...

**É uma ideia boba para chamar a atenção e apelar a participação das pessoas. Mas se calhar melhor que não haver qualquer ideia!**

Em certa forma são até parecido ás medalhas. Contudo existe algumas diferenças.

As medalhas duram para sempre e grande parte delas pode ser obtida num longo espaço de tempo, enquanto os chapéus duram por um tempo limitado e tem que realizar acções durante um pequeno intervalo de tempo.

Os chapéus não beneficiam nem o usuário nem a comunidade. Abstenha-se de ganhar chapéus da mesma forma que as medalhas. Participe mas use o senso comum e não faca aquilo que não deve só para obter um chapéu.

**Faca deste evento aquilo que ele realmente quer incentivar. Participe, participe mais, mas sempre com sabedoria**

Comment: Embora a minha resposta seja um bocado neutra o meu voto pessoalmente é nao. Mas entendo porque a comunidade queira participar. Se os utilzadores participarem com sabedoria, dá tudo certo :)

Answer (score -10):

O Talmude enfatiza a necessidade de se ter sempre o temor a Deus sobre a cabeça. Na sua maioria, os judeus utilizam o quipá apenas em ocasiões solenes e de devoção, enquanto alguns utilizam-no o dia inteiro, ilustrando a necessidade de se temer a Deus em todos os momentos da vida. Seu uso é usualmente associado ao reconhecimento da superioridade divina sobre o ser humano, sendo símbolo de humildade perante o Criador e de submissão à sua vontade.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Hehehe...Só um pouco de história...

Comment: Mas é a favor ou contra? Rs

Comment: @Math Se tiver Hood sou a favor...heheh ou Quipá..lol