# Onde estão os chapéus?

Tags: debate, winterbash-2016

Os chapéus eram figurinhas que se usava em cima da imagem de perfil. Embora não fossem fundamentais eu os achava interessantes e que eram uma motivação extra responder perguntas para obtê-los, mas agora parece que sumiram. Tem algum motivo especial para terem retirado os chapéus? Alguém mais além de mim curtia essas figurinhas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontrada a resposta:

Trata-se de um evento chamado Winter Bash promovido no final do ano:
[Chapéus, sapatos, roupas usadas quem tem 2016](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5497/chap%c3%a9us-sapatos-roupas-usadas-quem-tem-2016/5500#5500)