# Vamos ter chapéus neste ano de 2017?

Tags: debate, winterbash-2017

No [Winter Bash 2016](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5497/chap%C3%A9us-sapatos-roupas-usadas-quem-tem-2016) tivemos muitos chapéus legais, vários tamanhos, cores e formas, era chapéu pra qualquer gosto :D! E uma coisa legal, é ter um chapéu para cada dia da semana \o/

Assim sendo, eu gostaria de fazer uma pergunta para a comunidade:

## Vamos ter chapéus neste ano de 2017?

Eu quero muito experimentar uns chapéus novos! E vocês? O que acham?

Comment: Tem moderadores traduzindo os textos, isso é uma dica.

Comment: [Isso é outra dica](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGDQi.jpg)

Comment: @Math ["- Você é sem dúvida o pior pirata de quem já ouvi falar. - Mas ouviu falar de mim"](https://youtu.be/uNoQCoKUt80)

Comment: Eu ja ganhei alguns! Que top! É o
Meu primeiro ano ativo no stackoverflow. 

Comment: O que são esses chapéis? Como obtê-los? O que eles fazem?

Answer (score 5):

### Já temos!!!

Apesar de ter meu motivo para achar que os chapéus são um problema, diferente do SOen, no ano passado até que notei que o pessoal estava mais comportado e o chapeis foram divertidos, então esse ano vou participar também.

Então vamos aproveitar, mas com responsabilidade durante o evento, assim me disse o amigo [urso](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5501/3635):

[image: urso SOpt]

Comment: Gente, o Hisoka ficou muito bom com esse chapéu...